# How to simplify symbolic matrix multiplication using the associativity of scalar multiplication?

Tags: matrix, symbolic, ncalgebra

My input is `(2A).(3B)`. Is there a way to get `6A.B`? All I could get back from *Mathematica* was `(2A).(3B)` itself.

I'd like to make use of the associativity of scalar multiplication in symbolic dot products. How can I get there?

Comment: You must use curly brackets: `{2 A}.{3 B}`

Comment: @eldo, be careful. `{2 B}.{3 A}` gives `6AB` also, but matrices can be non-commutative.

Comment: This may be too specific: `Thread[(2 A).(3 B), Times] /. Dot[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] :> a b`

Comment: In fact, I got a lot of such things after some computation. Is there any simple way to do that at one go?

Comment: I'm trying to define a new definition of Dot with (a*b/(Part[Variables[(a)]][[1]]*Part[Variables[(b)]][[1]]))*(Part[
     Variables[(a)]][[1]].(Part[Variables[(b)]][[1]])). However, it doesn't seem to be an easy problem to me.

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to work with non-commutative algebras like the matrix multiplication I recommend you try the [NCAlgebra package](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/).

```
<< NC`
<< NCAlgebra`
(2 a) ** (3 b)
```

> ```
> 6 a ** b
> ```

P.S. In `NCAlgebra` all lowercase variables are non-commutative by default.